# different ways of using delete function in c++

Tags: c++

In c++ i have used delete to destroy array allocated on heap memory.
what the difference in:

1.delete [] pointer_name;
2.delete pointer_name [];

and is there anyway in by which a variable can be defined without a constructor.

Comment: `delete[]` deletes an array. `delete` deletes a single element.

Comment: referrence http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]

Answer (score 0):

```
delete [] pointer_name;
```

This is used to deallocate memory of an array that was declared with new[].

```
delete pointer_name[];
```

This has no meaning and will likely give you an error.

Refer to this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) for more information on the correct uses of `delete`.

As for your second question, a class will always have a default constructor.
Refer to this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) for more information on default constructors.

Comment: no a class will not always have a default constructor. A default constructor is a constructor that can be called with no arguments, its not called "default" because every class has one. A class can even have no constructor at all.